# Regarding developing client through wsdl using Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am a new bie to the world of webservices ,i am asking the question which mite be reptitive one also,My query is that I have a wsdl which I can access by hitting the url of that wsdl in the browser , nowI want to make the client (generating java code) from that WSDL using the Axis 2 and from within eclipse itself , sp please advise
how to  proceed and please if possible I was looking for snapshots regarding making client from wsdl using Axis 2 from within eclipse itself, Please advise.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the Axis 2 documentation in their site... That will get you started. If you get stuck somewhere you can post it here....

Comment: @user, do you want to generate client code with Axis2? If so, you can use `wsdl2java` command provided by Axis2.

Comment: @ HiwayChe could you please provide an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

The following links should be useful to you.

[Quick Introduction To Axis2 Client API](http://wso2.org/library/290)

[Apache Axis2 User's Guide - Creating Clients](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#createclients)

[Java Apache Axis2 Web Services Client Examples](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Java_Apache_Axis2_Web_Services_Client_Examples)